# Convert Dates range column into months

Tags: sql, sql-server, rdbms

I have table call students and it has three columns ID, DateFrom, DateTo now I wanted to convert two Dates columns range Datefrom and Dateto into the one column months as output.

The table structure is as below. Date format (yyyy-mm-dd)

```
ID  DateFrom    DateTo
123 2019-12-03  2020-02-03
456 2020-02-03  2020-02-21
```

Output Structures

```
ID  Months
123 2019-12
123 2020-01
123 2020-02
456 2020-02
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using: mysql, sql-server, oracle...?

Comment: Please:  1) tag with the appropriate db vendor, 2) show table DDL.   thanks

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way to do it would be to use an auxiliary calendar table - that would make a simple join between both tables:

```
select distinct a.id, convert(char(7), b.[Date], 120) as month
from yourTable as a
join Calendar as b
    on a.DateFrom <= b.[Date]
    and a.DateTo >= b.[Date]
;
```

If you don't have a calendar table, you might want to consider adding one.

If you can't (or don't want to) add a calendar table, you can get the same result using a numbers (tally) table.
If you don't have a tally table you can generate one on the fly, using a common table expression.

Here's how your SQL would look like in that case:

```
WITH N10 AS
(
    SELECT n
    FROM (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9))V(n)
), Tally AS
(
    SELECT TOP (SELECT MAX(DATEDIFF(MONTH, DateFrom, DateTo)) + 1 FROM yourTable) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @@SPID) -1 As n
    FROM N10 As Ten
    CROSS JOIN N10 As Hundred
    --CROSS JOIN N10 As Thousand
)

SELECT [ID], CONVERT(char(7), Months, 120) As Months
FROM yourTable
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT N, DATEADD(MONTH, N, [DateFrom]) As Months
    FROM Tally 
) X
WHERE Months <= EOMONTH([DateTo])
ORDER BY Id, Months
```

Answer (score 0):

let's say that you table is called "dataval"
try this

```
;WITH minmax AS (
     SELECT Min(Eomonth(datefrom)) AS MinDate, 
            Max(Eomonth(dateto))   AS MaxDate 
     FROM   dataval), 
 months (date) AS (
     SELECT mindate 
     FROM   minmax 
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT Dateadd(month, 1, date) 
     FROM   months 
     WHERE  Dateadd(month, 1, date) <= (SELECT maxdate FROM minmax)) 
 SELECT ID, FORMAT (date, 'yyyy-MM') Months 
 FROM   dataval 
 INNER JOIN months 
    ON months.date BETWEEN Eomonth(dataval.datefrom) AND Eomonth(dataval.dateto)
```

fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=25430aad6d03711be99d3067e7a5a55f)